# REACT: Special characters not showing up correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, rxjs

Working on creating a checklist and special characters don't seem to show up correctly ie. & showing up as amp.

```
<label ng-repeat="item in List">
           <input checklist-model='selected_list' checklist-value='item.name'>
           <span class='someClass'>{{item.name}}</span>
</label>
```

I've tried using dangerouslySetInnerHTML but this just causes the checklist to break (blank checklist).

```
<span class='someClass'>dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item.name}}</span>
```

Would appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: ng-repeat is angular, are you certain your project is using react?

Comment: Ah JohnD, you're right. My bad there, will try to search for a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Whoops, this wasn't a REACT question, but Angular. Thanks to JohnD for letting me know. Used ng-bind-html to fix this:

```
<span class='someClass' ng-bind-html="item.name"></span>
```